# Draw line charts by days/weeks/months from a timestamp

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, chart.js, data-visualization

I want to analyze visit logs of my website. The website stores an array of `moment.js` time, each time there is a new visit on the website, it pushes a `moment.js` time to the array.

From that input, I want to draw line charts to show the `number of visits` `day by day`, `week by week` and `month by month`. In [this example](https://jsbin.com/qelosaceqa/3/edit?html,output) of showing number of visits day by day, I have to prepare the data (of x-axis and y-axis) by myself:

```
var enumerateDaysBetweenDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
    var dates = {};
    var currDate = startDate.clone().startOf('day').add(-1,'days');
    var lastDate = endDate.clone().startOf('day');
    while(currDate.add(1, 'days').diff(lastDate) <= 0) {
        var x = currDate.clone(); 
        dates[x.format('YYYY-MM-DD')] = { "numberOfVisits": 0 };
    }
    return dates;
};

var startDate = moment({ year : 2017, month : 10, day : 1 });
var endDate = moment({ year : 2017, month : 10, day : 30 });
var res = enumerateDaysBetweenDates(startDate, endDate)
for (var i = 0; i < logs.length; i++) {
    var date = moment.utc(logs[i]).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    res[date].numberOfVisits++
}

// change format:
var r = [];
for (var d in res) {
    if (res.hasOwnProperty(d)) {
        var a = d.split("-");
        var b = Date.UTC(a[0], a[1] - 1, a[2]);
        r.push([b, res[d].numberOfVisits])
    }
}
```

To draw a chart for weeks or months, I have to re-prepare the data. Does anyone know if there is a way, a parameter or a library that permits of automatically drawing the charts?

PS: here is [an example by chart.js](https://jsbin.com/gusewoduxu/5/edit?html,output)

Comment: highcharts example is not working properly getting console error _Cannot read property 'numberOfVisits' of undefined_

Comment: I don't see that error in the console... it works on my side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Highstock** provides `dataGroupig` functionality that seems to be what you're looking for.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/avd0gqgr/

I forced data grouping and overwrote its units on button click.

```
//options
  xAxis: {
    ordinal: false
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataGrouping: {
        forced: true,
        approximation: 'sum'
      }
    }
  },
(...)

// button
$('#months').click(function() {
  chart.update({
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataGrouping: {
          units: [
            [
              'month', [1]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

**Docs reference:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping

Comment: Indeed, that's what I am after... I have made [another example](https://jsbin.com/gecuyugeme/4/edit?html,output) with different data. changing `units: [['day', [1]]]` to `units: [['week', [1]]]` shows the difference...